# How can I remotely query Registry using WMI from a 32-bit application?

Tags: .net, registry, wmi

I need to remotely collect the data about installed software on a device from these 2 locations:

- `HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\`
- `HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\`

For that I am using WMI class `StdRegProv`.
Application which collects the data needs to be 32-bit.

The problem is that I recive only the data from `Wow6432Node` and it is doubled. E.g. If there are 3 records in 64-bit part and 5 records in 32-bit part I will receive 10 records (5 unique) in total.

How can I stop WMI from doing the redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB not C# but this worked for me and is coded to work whether your app is running as a 32 bit process or as a 64 bit process. The magic bit is the IF statement around line 8 - IntPtr.Size will only be 4 if your process is a 32 bit process.

```vb
   Public Function GetSettingEx(PredefinedKey As PredefinedKeyEnum, Section As String, Key As String, Default_Renamed As String, sComputerName As String, Optional b64Bit As Boolean = False) As String
       Try
           Dim options As New ConnectionOptions()
           options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate

           Dim scope As New ManagementScope("\\" & sComputerName & "\root\default", options)

           If IntPtr.Size = 4 Then
               scope.Options.Context.Add("__ProviderArchitecture", 64)
               scope.Options.Context.Add("__RequiredArchitecture", True)
           End If

           scope.Connect()

           Dim regclass As New ManagementClass(scope, New ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), Nothing)

           Dim hDefKey As UInteger = MapPredefinedKeyToWMI(PredefinedKey)

           Dim methodParams As ManagementBaseObject = regclass.GetMethodParameters("EnumValues")
           methodParams("hDefKey") = hDefKey
           methodParams("sSubKeyName") = Section

           Dim outParams As ManagementBaseObject = regclass.InvokeMethod("EnumValues", methodParams, Nothing)

           If CUInt(outParams("ReturnValue")) = 0 Then
               Dim valueNames As String() = DirectCast(outParams.Properties("sNames").Value, String())
               Dim valueTypes As Integer() = DirectCast(outParams.Properties("Types").Value, Integer())

               If valueNames Is Nothing Then
                   Return ""
               End If

               For i As Integer = 0 To valueNames.Length - 1
                   Dim name As String = valueNames(i)
                   If name = Key Then
                       Dim regtype As RegistryTypes = CType(valueTypes(i), RegistryTypes)

                       Select Case regtype
                           Case RegistryTypes.REG_SZ, RegistryTypes.REG_EXPAND_SZ
                               Dim methodParamssz As ManagementBaseObject = regclass.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue")
                               methodParamssz("hDefKey") = hDefKey
                               methodParamssz("sSubKeyName") = Section
                               methodParamssz("sValueName") = Key

                               Dim outParamssz As ManagementBaseObject = regclass.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", methodParamssz, Nothing)

                               Dim value As Object = outParamssz.Properties("sValue").Value
                               Return CStr(value)


                           Case RegistryTypes.REG_MULTI_SZ
                               Dim methodParamssz As ManagementBaseObject = regclass.GetMethodParameters("GetMultiStringValue")
                               methodParamssz("hDefKey") = hDefKey
                               methodParamssz("sSubKeyName") = Section
                               methodParamssz("sValueName") = Key

                               Dim outParamssz As ManagementBaseObject = regclass.InvokeMethod("GetMultiStringValue", methodParamssz, Nothing)

                               Dim value As Object = outParamssz.Properties("sValue").Value
                               Return String.Join(",", DirectCast(value, String()))

                           Case RegistryTypes.REG_DWORD
                               Dim methodParamsdword As ManagementBaseObject = regclass.GetMethodParameters("GetDWORDValue")
                               methodParamsdword("hDefKey") = hDefKey
                               methodParamsdword("sSubKeyName") = Section
                               methodParamsdword("sValueName") = Key

                               Dim outParamsdword As ManagementBaseObject = regclass.InvokeMethod("GetDWORDValue", methodParamsdword, Nothing)

                               Dim value As Object = outParamsdword.Properties("uValue").Value
                               Return CStr(value)

                           Case RegistryTypes.REG_QWORD
                               Dim methodParamsqword As ManagementBaseObject = regclass.GetMethodParameters("GetQWORDValue")
                               methodParamsqword("hDefKey") = hDefKey
                               methodParamsqword("sSubKeyName") = Section
                               methodParamsqword("sValueName") = Key

                               Dim outParamsqword As ManagementBaseObject = regclass.InvokeMethod("GetQWORDValue", methodParamsqword, Nothing)

                               Dim value As Object = outParamsqword.Properties("uValue").Value
                               Return CStr(value)

                           Case RegistryTypes.REG_BINARY
                               Dim methodParamsbinary As ManagementBaseObject = regclass.GetMethodParameters("GetBinaryValue")
                               methodParamsbinary("hDefKey") = hDefKey
                               methodParamsbinary("sSubKeyName") = Section
                               methodParamsbinary("sValueName") = Key

                               Dim outParamsbinary As ManagementBaseObject = regclass.InvokeMethod("GetBinaryValue", methodParamsbinary, Nothing)

                               Dim value As Object = outParamsbinary.Properties("uValue").Value
                               Return BitConverter.ToString(DirectCast(value, Byte()))

                           Case Else
                               Throw New Exception("Unknown registry type : " & regtype.ToString)
                       End Select
                   End If
               Next
           End If


           Return Default_Renamed
       Catch ex As Exception
           Return Default_Renamed
       End Try
   End Function



Public Enum PredefinedKeyEnum
    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    HKEY_USERS = &H80000003
    HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA = &H80000004
    HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = &H80000005
    HKEY_DYN_DATA = &H80000006
End Enum

    Private Function MapPredefinedKeyToWMI(PredefinedKey As PredefinedKeyEnum) As UInteger

        Dim ret As UInteger

        Select Case PredefinedKey
            Case PredefinedKeyEnum.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
                ret = 2147483648 ' &H80000000
            Case PredefinedKeyEnum.HKEY_CURRENT_USER
                ret = 2147483649 ' &H80000001
            Case PredefinedKeyEnum.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
                ret = 2147483650 ' &H80000002
            Case PredefinedKeyEnum.HKEY_USERS
                ret = 2147483651 ' &H80000003
            Case PredefinedKeyEnum.HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA
                ret = 2147483652 ' &H80000004
            Case PredefinedKeyEnum.HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG
                ret = 2147483653 ' &H80000005
            Case PredefinedKeyEnum.HKEY_DYN_DATA
                ret = 2147483654 ' &H80000006
            Case Else
                Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid predefinedKey")
        End Select

        Return ret

    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. When I first tried adding the Options.Context (before asking the question) I had mixed results. After some experimenting I have found the solution - Options.Context need to be set again after initial scope has been created. Without this solution works only in 20% of devices (in my environment) and if I add the additional step it works for all. Regarding the x64 check I was using the `Win32_OperatingSystem` WMI class.

Comment: I've since changed this class so that the regClass variable becomes scoped to class level, that means that you only have to create it once. This speeded up a WMI/remote reg discovery from 5 minutes to about 3 minutes. It should also mean that the options persist. I've seen some code online that explicitly removes the options, so check you haven't got that in there. Mine seems to be stable for now, its discovered a network of about 50 machines with hundreds of reg settings queried on each machine.